# Closed but not exact one-form on $S^2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

I would like to know whether there is any nice prescription to give an example of a closed but not exact one-form on $S^2$ (not the $3$-ball). I assume to take some points out of this surface, e.g. 3.

On $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$ a closed but not exact one-form would be $\frac{x dy-y dx}{x^2+y^2}$. Can I use this also for $S^2$?

Comment: The only thing stopping you is that the form isn't defined on two points of $S^2$. Indeed, there's something stopping us from finding such a form defined on all of $S^2$; can you think what that is?

Comment: This cannot happen on $S^2$ because the non-exactness of a closed form must come from a hole on the surface (in rough words). You should try to prove the following : let $S$ be a surface which is simply connected(this express the fact that $S$ has no hole), then every closed $1$-form is exact.

Comment: Ok I read a bit fast your hypothesis and missed the fact that you removed 3 points. Whatever, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for in your comment. Could you precise a bit ?

Comment: @Hamurabi, taking 2 points out is sufficient to have such forms, as your example above well shows. What exactly are you asking for, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, take a diffeomorphism from $\mathbb S^2\setminus {\rm two\ points}$ to $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ and pull back the form that you have there.

If for example the two points that you remove are $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,0,-1)$ then you can write every point as $(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi,z)$ and $\phi$ is well-defined up to multiples of $2\pi$. Hence $d\phi$ is a well-defined one-form which does what you want.

Indeed the description in the previous paragraph is unnecessarily complicated. If you work it out you arrive exactly at the form $\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}$ that you mentioned in the question. Of course, $x=r\cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\phi$.